# Django admin show __str__ value in name

Tags: django, django-models

I have a many to many field like this:

```
class Retailer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    city_gps = models.ManyToManyField(City, blank=True, related_name='retailers', db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        retailer_city = ""
        if self.city_gps:
            retailer_city = self.city_gps.all().first().name

        return slugify(self.name) + slugify(retailer_city)
```

I would like the admin to show a combination of the name and all related cities. However, when I set the admin to show this field like this:

```
class RetailerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ['name', 'city_gps', 'icon_tag', 'logo_tag', 'header_tag']
```

I get the error:

> : (admin.E109) The value of
>   'list_display[1]' must not be a ManyToManyField.

So, how can I solve this? Is there a way to show the value of the `__str__` method in the the admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [the docs for `list_display` in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> `ManyToManyField` fields aren’t supported, because that would entail executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you want to do this nonetheless, give your model a **custom method**, and add that method’s name to `list_display`. (See below for more on custom methods in `list_display`.)

So you can define this *custom method* either in your `models.py` or (I think the more [explicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) way), directly in your `admin.py`:

```
class RetailerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ['name', 'icon_tag', 'logo_tag', 'header_tag', 'retailer_city']

    def retailer_city(self, obj):
        city_gps = obj.city_gps
        retailer_city = city_gps.all().first().name if city_gps else ''

        return slugify(obj.name) + slugify(retailer_city)
```

Note that `retailer_city` is added in `list_display`.